# If Two Columns Match In Separate Sheets, The Insert Separate Column Value From Sheet1 Into Sheet2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sets of data with about 50k rows in set 1 and 35k rows in set 2 .

There is some overlap between the data which can be matched together by the "Order ID" column.

In set 1 of data I have among other columns a field name for the sales person who took the order.

In data set 2, I have a list of orders with order ID's and it does not include the sales person name. Some orders occur in both data sets (as determined by if the order id matches) others are unique to one data set or the other.

Is there a way to make a blank column in data set 2 and say "if customer ID matches customer id field in data set 1, then insert sales person name value from data set 1"

Here are screenshots to give you better idea of what I mean.

Data set 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpNT6.png

Data set 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXYy0.png

Is there a way to say "If column A in data set 2 matches exactly Column A from data set 1, then insert value from column E in data set 1 into column E in data set 2, if not leave blank."

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The easiest way would probably be the `VLOOKUP` function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the comments, `VLOOKUP` is one way of doing it. The more flexible way to retrieve the information is the combination of `Index` and `Match` to insert in Column E of Data Set 2:

```
=INDEX(DataSet1[Column E],MATCH(DataSet2[Column A],DataSet1[Column A],0))
```

Wrap it in an `IF` statement to get the "empty" cell if there is no match:

```
=IF(INDEX(DataSet1[Column E],MATCH(DataSet2[Column A],DataSet1[Column A],0))=0,"",Index(DataSet1[Column E],MATCH(DataSet2[Column A],DataSet1[Column A],0)))
```

or in a `IFERROR` if the matching value from Data Set 2 is not in Data Set 1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DataSet1[Column E],MATCH(DataSet2[Column A],DataSet1[Column A],0))=0,"")
```

For a detailed explanation on how it works (and why it is better than `VLOOKUP`): https://exceljet.net/index-and-match